# How to create a correct statement: the usage of the verb TO DO

Tags: expressions, verbs, word-usage, do

I would like to create a statement for an exercise.

*Pretend you are a positive character from a fairy tale. Describe what you see, **what you do**, how you feel.*

My question:

Is ok **what you do** or should I use **what you are doing**

Comment: Either way is fine, but if you want parallelism, balance, and symmetry,  perhaps the use of "are seeing," "are doing," and "are feeling" would be better. Or, "what you see, what you do, and how you feel." (I used "and" before "how you feel," but that's optional. Without "and," you have the figure of speech called asyndeton, the deliberate omission of a conjunction.)

Comment: Both forms are ok. The progressive form has a limitation compared to the simple present form as to the permanency of the action/situation. Moreover, verbs of perception like *see*, *feel* etc. are not usually used in the progressive tense. It seems that **what you do** is preferable.